# The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved

Tags: java

> The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Please edit your post and add some additional information and a code example that produces an error.

Comment: `i am newly in java.` - I suggest you start with working examples from the Swing tutorial. Maybe the `FrameDemo.java` code from the section on [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).

Comment: that codes from the tutorial and it run smoothly, but when i start in my eclipse it produces some error, thanks camickr, VLS, Qiu

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the way you have created the project in Eclipse.  This code clearly has a Swing UI, but judging from what the Project Explorer panel is saying, you have creates the project as a Web Services project (or something like that).

I suggest that you delete the project and start again by creating a plain Java Application project.